# How to convert Isolated Stream to Base64String in Chunks in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, chunks

I am creating Video Recorder task in Windows Phone 8.1, I am saving video stream to IsolatedStorage, how do I convert it to Base64 using Chunks? If I am converting without chunks then Base64String becomes too long and Phone gets 'Hang'. See my code:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(isfStream);
int length = reader.BaseStream.Length;
int rr = Convert.ToInt32(length);
byte[] chunks = reader.ReadAllBytes[rr];

string finalstring = Convert.ToBase64String(chunks);
```

How to Convert using Chunks?
Please, suggest me, I stuck here for last three days!!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!